# Pulling data from one spreadsheets to another (IMPORTRANGE)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Trying to pull data from one spreadsheet to another:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LONz6rkyn4jM_aobSq1HIwjbeOXs2MhK6p_c_fNy8Wo/edit#gid=0
  I need to pull data to the column Anchor from the Google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4/edit#gid=0
- Column C - Anchor

When using this formula =VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE(“https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4/edit#gid=0”,“Internal!$A$2:$E$1000”),3)

getting an error.
Will really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the quotes. Instead of `“ ”`, you should be using `""`.

Use the next formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4/edit#gid=0","Internal!$A$2:$E$1000"),3)
```

Or even shorter (You only need the ID)

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1H0g2FwZZbD6L33KOhuXakuRbWDsIWDNGburMZ3Tf4T4","Internal!$A$2:$E$1000"),3)
```

**Check columns J-K**

Comment: quotes instead of commas

Comment: Translation problem. Thank you @MikeSteelson